# why forEach() doesn't work in this object loop?

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

Why forEach doesn't work for the following? I tried it a few times and it always return "unexpected token".

```
// for loop
for(item in items){
        if (items[item].id===idNum){
            console.log(items[item]);
        }
    }

// the for loop works. 

// forEach()

items.forEach(item=>if(item.id===idNum){console.log(item)})
// this returned error message "unexpected token"
```

Comment: Because you can not forEach an object. This is part of the Array.prototype. You can `Object.keys(items).forEach(` instead.

Comment: what does `items` look like?

Comment: The error comes from an invalid arrow function structure, though.

Comment: `item=>if(item.id===idNum){console.log(item)}` that `if` is not an expression, you can't use it there. It should be something like `(item) => {if ... }`

Answer (score 4):

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the
>   implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit
>   return statement

reference :- [Arrow function body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)

Because this syntax is not correct.

```
items.forEach(item=>if(item.id===idNum){console.log(item)})
```

You need to use `{}` here

```
items.forEach(item=>{
if(item.id===idNum){console.log(item)}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use brackets for function body:

```js
let items = [ {id:1}, {id:2} ];
let idNum = 2;

items.forEach(item => {
  if (item.id === idNum) { console.log(item) }
})
```